# How to tell TS that if one variable is true then another one exists

Tags: typescript

let's say I have a variable that represents a state of a component, it can be either true or false – `isDialogPermanent: boolean`

And I have a variable that can be either `string` or `undefined` – `username: string|undefined`

If `isDialogPermanent` true then I would like to execute one function, otherwise another:

```
if (isDialogPermanent) {
    someFunction(username);
} else {
    anotherOne();
}
```

The problem is that TS fairly complains that username might be `undefined`(coz `someFunction()` requires param to be `string`). Although in my architecture if `isDialogPermanent` is true then `username` exists for sure (unless something unexpected happened)

How to tell TypeScript that if `isDialogPermanent` is true then `username` exists?

I have some workarounds to avoid TS error like:

1. add `as string`, e.g. `someFunction(username as string)`
2. along with isDialogPermanent check username, e.g. if (isDialogPermanent && !!username) {...}

Although I don't like both of them coz it feels like I'm fighting against TS errors instead of make it work right (coz all these worksarounds only to fix TS errors and don't make code better)

Don't focus on my code snippet, the real example is more complex so I tried to make it as easy as possible just to highlight the problem source.

Comment: Create a union type `{isDialogPermanent: true, username: string} | {isDialogPermanent: false}`

Comment: As zerkms says, a discriminated union is the way to go here. Typescript does control-flow type narrowing, but it cannot keep track of a relationship between different variables.

Comment: @zerkms I see, thanks for your answer! 

So in my example I need to make an object with this union type and then pass not the original username but the one from the object with the union type?

e.g. `const unionTypeObject: {isDialogPermanent: true, username: string} | {isDialogPermanent: false} = {isDialogPermanent: isDialogPermanent, username: username}` and then `if (unionTypeObject.isDialogPermanent) {someFunction(unionTypeObject.username)}`?

Comment: As you said, if something unexpected happens `username` might not be in par with `isDialogPermanent` so it's quite reasonable to check if `username` is not `undefined` (and, btw, `!!username` doesn't check this since an empty string is falsy)